# Does aligned rank transform ANOVA require normally distributed data?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, normality-assumption

Initially, I wanted to do a two-factorial (4x3) repeated measures ANOVA in order to analyse my data.
To be more precise, I do have two factors with factor1 having 4 levels (A, B, C, D), factor2 having 3 levels (t1, t2, t3). In addition, it is a repeated measures design as all 28 subjects (s) are confronted with all the 4 levels (A, B, C, D) within the 3 timepoints (t1, t2, t3). However, it turned out, that according to Shapiro Wilk test my data are not normally distributed. That is why now I wanted to use the aligned rank transform ANOVA as a non-parametric alternative for a two-factorial rmANOVA.
Within this method, data are aligned before doing the ANOVA.

**The question is: After alignment, do the aligned data need to be normally distributed before performing the ANOVA for a valid outcome?**
I am not sure about this, as the ART seems to be a non-parametric method, but still includes an ANOVA (with normally distributed data as a premise).

I am using the R-library "ARTool" and have come up with the following code:

```
library(ARTool)
aligned_data <- art(dependentVariable ~ factor1 * factor2 + Error(s), data=data)
```

Now does the following Shapiro Test need to tell me, that my data is normally distributed in order to continue and trust the results?

```
shapiro.test(residuals(aligned_data))

anova(aligned_data)
```

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. ANOVA on ranks of nonnormal data have been used as a sort of nonparametric tests. Of course the ranks are not truly normally distributed, but they are small-ish integers distributed roughly symmetrically and usually with no fall outliers.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question but what about using a two-way repeated measures ANOVA on trimmed means instead? Does not require data normality and/or homogeneity of variances. In R you can do this with the function `wwtrim` from the WRS package.

Besides that the Shapiro-Wilk test will be often significant even if your data is normally distributed provided that you have a large enough sample size.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a one-factor ANOVA with five levels of the factor and 40
exponential replications per level. It is difficult to imagine that the
F-statistic would have the anticipated F distribution on account of the
right-skewed exponential data.

```
set.seed(811)
x1 = rexp(40, .10)
x2 = rexp(40, .12);  x3 = rexp(40, .12)
x4 = rexp(40, .15);  x5 = rexp(40, .15)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
g = as.factor(rep(1:5, each=40))
boxplot(x ~ g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

An 'oneway' test om R does not require equal variances in the five levels
of the factor. This test may tolerate the exponential data better than would a standard ANOVA. It rejects the null hypothesis that all level means are equal
with P-value about 3%. On account of the exponential data, I would doubt whether this P-value is accurate. Multiple comparisons might be done with Welch 2-sample t tests, with some protection (such as Bonferroni) against false discovery from
multiple tests on the same data.

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means 
        (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 2.8842, num df = 4.000, denom df = 95.898, p-value = 0.0265
```

The rank-transformed data have more nearly equal variances and are more nearly normal. [Data at each level pass the Shapiro-Wilk normality test; not shown.] Thus a standard ANOVA might be used.

Because the usual assumptions for an ANOVA are more nearly met here, perhaps the P-value here is roughly accurate. Again here `oneway.test` rejects the null hypothesis.
On account of the rank transformation, interpretations of effect sizes
in *ad hoc* test must be made with care.

```
boxplot(rank(x) ~ g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
oneway.test(rank(x)~g)

    One-way analysis of means 
    (not assuming equal variances)

data:  rank(x) and g
F = 2.8508, num df = 4.000, denom df = 97.323, p-value = 0.0278
```

Standard one-way ANOVA:

```
anova(lm(rank(x)~g))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: rank(x)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
 g           4  36682  9170.5  2.8386 0.02554 *
 Residuals 195 629968  3230.6                  
 ---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: These methods are somewhat ad hoc.  Consider using full models that make use only of ranks of Y, i.e., semiparametric ordinal models.  Resources are [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).